# Soup 'fork' source

Tags: soup, utensils

So, this is more a question about food etiquette/trivia than cooking, but this community seemed to be the closest fit.

Is there a specialized fork-like utensil that was used for soup in western high-society scenarios, or are you aware of a fictional source which may have made that claim (like in a joke about obscure dining etiquette)?

I know that I have not encountered this device personally, but I do know that I obtained this idea from visual media, like a show or movie, but I can't remember if it was fictional or not.
Associations I am making with this memory are, these may or may not be accurate:
For a specific or tight category of soups (I want to say Consomme or another empty broth); the utensil appeared non-standard is some way, less strong is why I thought so, I want to say it had only a couple of tines &/or was very slender?; the utensil had a specific name that implied a unique utensil not a fork/spoon variant; it was used by the person eating the soup, not for serving or preparation, but I feel like I remember its use not being straight forward, like maybe to stir the broth before drinking?; I don't believe I saw anyone actually use it, but rather a discussion about using it, like you may see on a travel/restaurant show.

The only thing I have been able to find over many searches are a couple of references of 'Vichyssoise Fork' which both absolutely lacked informative context (a screen name and a picture with a high society cat saying you must use the V.F.).  That term doesn't feel right/jog memory, but maybe if I knew more about it it would.  I know Vichyssoise is not a broth, debatable origin, I am not finding any references to people using a unique utensil for it, and I feel that the mention I encountered was highlighted because of the difficulty of using it with the intended dish if used improperly/ignorantly.

Thank you, apologies for obscurity/lack of known factors.

Comment: Is it possible that it was for aspic? Aspic server #3 http://www.replacements.com/piecetype/flat3.htm

Comment: Etiquette differs from culture to culture, country to country and even region to region.  Whatever is considered good etiquette in one culture is extremely rude in another, and the same goes for utensils.  Which etiquette are you referring to? (as your profile doesn't mention any cultural background)

Comment: If it exists you can bet its Victorian, almost everything had its own cutlery, the marrow scoop, the sardine server, the bacon fork and a whole set of different cheese implements. I did check the list of cutlery held by the V&A museum in London and they don't have one.

Comment: To be honest, this is a perfect description of a [spork](http://cdn.outdoorgearlab.com/photos/8/53/206795_10339_M.jpg). Though a spork is all but a fine cuisine utensil, but a piece of outdoor equipment. On the other hand: I prepare dishes with my bushcraft knife... ;)

Comment: Thank you all, these are great, it was answered, but it does sound like something that would be used for aspic, it is essentially based on Victorian culture albeit via comedic exaggeration (which I had failed to mention the possible backgrounds where I was bouncing between victorian/french), and my description does sound kind of like a spork, these all could have potentially led to a valid answer if it wasn't from a comedy skit.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be thinking of a sketch from the comedy show "That Mitchell and Webb Look" in which a snobby waiter insists that a fork be used to eat soup:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSj5stmFkQ0

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, seeing the clip jogged my memory, this is absolutely the source for my thoughts.  Also, the clip explicitly cites both Consomme and Vichyssoise Fork explaining why both those thoughts are there.  This is much appreciated, glad to know that is just sourced in hyperbolic comedy!

Comment: Do you have another link. That one says "Video Not Available"?

Comment: @bob A bit late, but I've edited the answer with a correct link. It needs to be approved, so until then it's also here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSj5stmFkQ0.